# icon does not show up on tabBar

Tags: reactjs, react-native, font-awesome, mobile-development

I use fontawesome to add icon to tab button but the only label shows up, NOT icon:

```
<Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: "Home",
          tabBarAccessibilityLabel: "Home",
          tabBarTestID: "tabbar-Home",
          tabBarIcon: () => (
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faInfoCircle} color={'white'} size={30} />
          ),
        }}
```

I use ReactNative, NOT expo!

Comment: Are you using `Expo`?

Comment: React Native, not Expo

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Expo` then, You can do like this

```
import { FontAwesome5 } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons';
```

and in tab options write like this

```
<Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: "Home",
          tabBarAccessibilityLabel: "Home",
          tabBarTestID: "tabbar-Home",
          tabBarIcon: () => (
            <FontAwesome name="info-circle" size={24} color="black" />
          ),
        }}
```

Or

```
<Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: "Home",
          tabBarAccessibilityLabel: "Home",
          tabBarTestID: "tabbar-Home",
          tabBarIcon: () => (
            <FontAwesome5 name="info-circle" size={24} color="black" />
          ),
        }}
```

---

Now if you are using `React Native CLI`

Then firstly install [React Native Vector Icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#installation)

then write like this

```
import FontAwesome5 from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';
```

and in Tab options write like this

```
<Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: "Home",
          tabBarAccessibilityLabel: "Home",
          tabBarTestID: "tabbar-Home",
          tabBarIcon: () => (
            <FontAwesome5 name="info-circle" size={24} color="black" />
          ),
        }}
```